# C Print Data from loop after loop ends

Tags: c

So, I managed to wrangle some code to get part of my program working.  My program has to have a prompt to enter grades (done), repeat in a loop until broken (doneish), and print results of each grade entered.  The last part is where I am stuck. I can't seem to find a good way to get any grade I entered to print at the end.  I just want a "you entered ###, ###, ###," or something similar, but it can be up to 100 numbers.  Below is what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 100

int main(void) {
    int grade[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
    int entryCount = 0;
    char continueResponse;
    printf("Enter an grade of between 1 and 100. \n");
    printf("Enter a maximum of %d grades. \n", MAX_ARRAY_SIZE);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("Enter grade: ");
        scanf("%d", &grade[i]);
        printf("Continue? (y/n): ");
        scanf(" %c", &continueResponse);
        entryCount++;
        if(continueResponse == 'n' || continueResponse == 'N') {
            printf(" == End of Data Entry ==\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind this is third week of doing this, so I know next to nothing. If there's a "why did you do this like this", the answer is because that's how I've done it before and it works.  I appreciate any input!

Comment: You want to print the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your dataentry loop:

```
   for(i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
       ...
   }
```

You just have to add a second loop:

```
   for(i = 0; i < entryCount; i++) {
       printf ("%d ", grade[i]);
   }
```

Comment: Have a beer on me my friend, cause you're a friggin genius!  I appreciate it greatly!.  I added ("Your grade is : %d\n", grade[i]); worked liked a champ.

Answer (score 0):

You've recorded `entryCount` entries to the array, numbered `0` ... `entryCount - 1`; you'd use another `for` loop to print them. For nicer formatting we do not print ", " after the last number:

```
printf("You've entered ");
for (i = 0; i < entryCount; i++) {
    if (i == entryCount - 1) {
        printf("%d", grade[i]);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d, ", grade[i]);
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting advice, like I said, I'm super new at this!  I'll take all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

what I understood about your problem the following code would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 100
int main(void) {
int grade[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
int entryCount = 0;
char continueResponse;
printf("Enter an grade of between 1 and 100. \n");
printf("Enter a maximum of %d grades. \n", MAX_ARRAY_SIZE);
int i;
for(i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
printf("Enter grade: ");
scanf("%d", &grade[i]);
printf("Continue? (y/n): ");
scanf(" %c", &continueResponse);
entryCount++;

printf("you entred:\n");
for(int j=0;j<entryCount;j++)
{
    printf("%d ",grade[j]);

}

if(continueResponse == 'n' || continueResponse == 'N') {
    printf(" == End of Data Entry ==\n\n");
    break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: THanks for the help, i will use this when I have to build on the code for my next part of this project

Comment: why print every entered `grade` every time through the loop?  Suggest placing the 'print' loop after the 'entry' loop rather than inside the 'entry' loop

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans, 1) please consistently indent the code. indent after every opening brace: '{'. unindent before every closing brace: '}'.   2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, switch, case, default) via a blank line.